# Working of VoIP in a local network

Tags: ios, networking, voip, skype

We are working on an iOS application for which we need to learn how VoIP works on 2 devices/machines which are on same local network. When transferring files between 2 Skype users on same network, the file transfer is very fast. So there must be something different when 2 devices are connected which are on same network.

Maybe file sharing is different than VoIP and at least the VoIP part works the same way for users on same network or on different networks. But if its not the case then I would like to know whats the difference between connecting machines on same and different networks via Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Generaly VoIP is based on 3 protocols. SIP, RTP and RTCP.

Try to read some articles about SIP signalisation or SIP messages flow. The two devices within the same network can communicate directly or via SIP proxy. Basically the app has to support at least:

- REGISTER
- INVITE
- CANCEL
- BYE
- 100 Trying
- 180 Ringing
- 200 OK
- 486 Busy here

and few others SIP messages and status codes. Your app has to be able to handle SDP messages where the codec is negotiated - choose some free and open codec such as G.711 or iLBC. Within the SDP header RTP and RTCP port are negotiated as well, try to read something about SDP as well.

As this standard model uses multiple ports, it may cause issues when NAT is implemented, but this is not your case as you are within the same LAN.

Regardin the speed of transfer - if you are within the same network you shall not experience any impairments while calling - voice is transmitted in very small packets (i.e. 273 bytes) sent every 20 ms. If you are on wired 100 Mbit or 1 Gbit network, this shall work flawlessly. When on Wi-Fi some impairments may occur as it is not that much reliable.

Further information can be found here:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566.html

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt

I hope I answered your question at least a bit, if you have any further questions regarding VoIP feel free to ask.